# Shopify hreflang issues

Tags: html, shopify

I am getting issues with my hreflang tags on my Shopify store, specifically...

Broken hreflang URL
No self-referencing hreflang
This is what I have tried inside theme.liquid:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="{{ settings.color_secondary }}">
  
  
  {%- if canonical_url != blank -%}
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}">
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" hreflang="en-us">
    <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" hreflang="en-gb">
  {%- endif -%}
```

[image]

[image]

**Can anyone help me out and let me know what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you contacted shopify tech support?  That is what you pay for.